# What can we say about the product of elements from subgroups of the same order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group and $A$ and $B$ be order $p$ subgroups of $G$, where $p$ is a prime number greater than $2$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are subgroups with order $p$, they are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. For any elements $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, can we say that the product $ab=ba$ (product is commutative)?

Comment: Consider the wreath product $\Bbb Z_3\wr \Bbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A_4$, which has $A = \langle 1,2,3 \rangle$ and $B = \langle 2,3,4\rangle$ as order $3$ subgroups. But we see that
$$
(1,2,3)(2,3,4) = (1,2)(3,4) \neq (1,3)(2,4)=(2,3,4)(1,2,3)
$$

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric group on four symbols has several subgroups of order $3$. Try some experiments.